# Why is the water in a cup not inclined (opposite the cup) when the plane takes a turn?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, centrifugal-force, aircraft

When a aircraft takes a turn: Why is the water in a cup not inclined (opposite the cup)?

Comment: Because the plane banks as it makes the turn http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banked_turn

Comment: Because planes don't turn the way cars do, they turn the way bicycles do.

Comment: Actually, airplanes can make a wings-level turn, just by pressing a rudder pedal, and in that case, you and your coffee *do* feel a sideways force. But it's slow, uncomfortable, and very inefficient, compared to just banking into the turn.